# How to get the td element without using row number in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have the existing method like below,

```
getSpecificCell: function(tableObject, rowNumber, columnCss) {
  var ele = element(by.repeater(tableObject).row(rowNumber)).element(by.css('[' + columnCss + ']'));
  return ele;
}
```

Is that possible to do the same using the row text instead of rowNumber?

Form the below html I need to get the column value without using the row number

HTML sample:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="checkbox-column"></th>
      <th class="main-column main-column--checkbox">Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="(a, b) in tests" class="ng-scope" style="">
    <tr class="panel__sub-header">
      <td>
        <input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelectAll(a)" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <h4 class="ng-binding">ROW2</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
        <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.name</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
        <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.data</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody ng-repeat="(a, b) in tests" class="ng-scope" style="">
    <tr class="panel__sub-header">
      <td>
        <input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelectAll(a)" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <h4 class="ng-binding">ROW1</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
        <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.name</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
          <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.data</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can do it.But provide the relevant HTML code for the table element with some rows in it.

Comment: So based on which row value you need to filter out?

Comment: Yes. 
element(by.repeater(tableObject).row(rowNumber)).element(by.css('[' + columnCss + ']'));
From this instead of row(rowNumber) I need to use the row text (ROW2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` method to filter the array of WebElement. have a look at below example,

```
getSpecificCell: function(tableObject, expectedRowValue, columnCss) {
   var ele =element.all(by.repeater(tableObject).filter(function(rowElement){
      return rowElement.element(by.css("td h4")).getText().then(function(rowValue){
        return rowValue == expectedRowValue;
      })
   }).first().element(by.‌​css('[' + columnCss + ']'));

 return ele;
}
```

Comment: I tried this with element.all but facing the below error
`Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator by.repeater`

Comment: you need to use `element.all(by.repeater())`. updated my answer.

Comment: Yes after tried with `element.all(by.repeater())` only facing the above error